# Not all fields are returned in the query in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query(given below) which return matched record from the elastic search. But the returned data doesn't have my last field(position field) alone. FYI, the field is indexed and mapped. How will I get?.  I tried adding it in _source as well but couldn't fetch that one record

```
  {
_source: ['details.*','position']
     query: {
       bool: {
         should: [
           { "regexp": { "name": pattern } },
           {
             "fuzzy": {
               "name": {
                 "value": keywords,
                 "fuzziness": 3
               }
             }
           }
         ],
         "minimum_should_match": 1
       }
     },
     "from": skip,
     "size": size
   },
```

The below is my mappings:

```
    User.createMapping({
       "settings": {
           "analysis": {
               "analyzer": {
                   "my_analyzer": {
                       "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
                   }
               },
               "tokenizer": {
                   "my_tokenizer": {
                       "type": "edge_ngram",
                       "min_gram": 1,
                       "max_gram": 1000,
                       "token_chars": [
                           "letter",
                           "digit",
                           "whitespace"
                       ]
                   }
               }
           }
       },
       "mappings": {
           "user": {
               "properties": {
                   "details": {
                        "properties": {
                           "title": {
                               "type": "text"
                           },
                           'keywords': {
                               "type": "text"
                           },
                  'category': {
                               "type": "text"
                           }



                       }
                   },
                   "name": {
                       "type": "text"
                   },
                   "position": {
                       "type": "integer"
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }, function (err, mapping) {
    //handle errors
   });
```

Comment: Can you post the mapping and example document?

Comment: @sramalingam24 Can you please look into the updated question with mappings?

Comment: So your analyzer is tokenizing on digits, are you setting this analyzer on position field somewhere?

Comment: is it mandatory to add analyzer to position field?

Comment: No but I am just guessing what could be the reason

Comment: Will look into what you conveyed, but I could find the field in _plugins but nothing is getting stored in it.

Comment: Sounds like you are not indexing correctly, index a record using curl with a value for position specified and see if position is indexed